# Is the map $x\mapsto\|x\|_p^p$, defined in $L^p[0,1]$ ($1<p<\infty$), strictly convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Is the map $x\mapsto\|x\|_p^p$, defined in $L^p[0,1]$ (for $1<p<\infty$), **strictly** convex?

Maybe there is a classic inequality that can give the conclusion easily. Let me know if this is the case.

**Edit:** In the case it is not **strictly** convex, if we restrict the domain of $x\mapsto\|x\|_p^p$ to be the unit ball in $L^p[0,1]$, the map is **strictly** convex?

Comment: Maybe Minkowski's inequality?

Comment: $p=1$ must be treated separately.

Comment: @uniquesolution So let we suppose $1<p<\infty$

Comment: There is an answer to the equality case in Minkowski's inequality here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581257/when-does-equality-hold-in-the-minkowskis-inequality-fg-p-leq-f-p-g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for all $x,y$ and $\lambda\geq 0$, by the triangle (Minkowski) inequality:
$$|\!|\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y)|\!|_p^p\leq\left(\lambda|\!|x|\!|_p+(1-\lambda)|\!|y|\!|_p\right)^p$$
and the result follows from the strict convexity of the function $t\to t^p$ for $p>1$ and $t\geq 0$.

Comment: what if we take $x\neq y$ with $\|x\|_p=\|y\|_p$?

Comment: @Filburt - Equality means equality also in the triangle inequality, which implies for $p>1$ that $x=cy$ for some $c\geq 0$, and if they also have the same norm then $c=1$.

Answer (score -2):

Minkowski's inequality works:
$$\begin{align}||\lambda g+(1-\lambda)f||_p=\left(\int_X (|\lambda g+(1-\lambda) f|)^p \text{d}\mu \right)^{\frac 1p} &\le \left(\int_X (\lambda |g|)^p \text{d}\mu \right)^{\frac 1p}+\left(\int_X ((1-\lambda) |f|)^p \text{d}\mu \right)^{\frac 1p}\\ &=\lambda ||g||_p+(1-\lambda)||f||_p \end{align}$$

Comment: hold on, how do we get the *strictly* inequality? ($\lambda\in]0,1[$)

Comment: the equality holds if and only if $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent... So if we suppose $f\neq g$ (different classes), is there a way to conclude $\|\lambda g+(1-\lambda)f\|_p<\lambda \|g\|_p+(1-\lambda)\|f\|_p$? thought they can be different and still linearly dependent

Comment: @Filburt For $p=1$ equality can hold also for independent functions, provided they have non-intersecting supports.

Comment: So I made another restriction ($1<p<\infty$) and edited the question

Comment: The question is asking about $\|x\|_p^p$, not $\|x\|_p$.

Comment: @Did thats right

Comment: $x^p$ is convex increasing, and composition of a convex function by a convex increasing function is convex

Comment: @GuachoPerez "Strictly Convex" and "Convex" are not the same thing.

Comment: But $x^p$ is strictly convex